# How to get full windows path in python

Tags: python, windows, path

How can I transform a shortened path to full path in python? For example take this full path

`C:\Test\PathToMyDirectoryWithLongName\test.txt`

which got transformed into

`C:\Test\PATHTO~\test.txt`.

How do I transform it back?

Comment: How did it get "transformed"?

Comment: It went through a blackbox :-) Don't know how it got transformed. Shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well, my only thought was that if this was shortened on another system and you are reading this from stored data then you might have difficulty getting the long path as the way it is shortened is dependent on the system it was shortened on.

Comment: I understand. No, it is all happening on the same system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`win32api.GetLongPathName`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__GetLongPathName_meth.html):

```
>>> win32api.GetLongPathName(r'c:\progra~1')
'c:\\Program Files'
```

and [`win32api.GetShortPathName`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__GetShortPathName_meth.html):

```
>>> win32api.GetShortPathName(r'c:\Program Files')
'c:\\PROGRA~1'
```

NOTE: You need to install [`pywin32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) to use above functions.

Comment: `GetLongPathName` looks good but it raises an exception if I try to use it on a not-shortened path like `win32api.GetLongPathName(r'C:\tmp\test.txt')` Actually I don't really know if my path is shortened or not. Any simple workaround for this? Or do I have to catch the exception?

Comment: @arminb, How about check whether the path contains `~` or not? `path = win32api.GetLongPathName(path) if '~' in path else path`

Comment: ok, it looks like the path must exist, otherwise I get the error. If it exists and it is not shortened it works as well.

Comment: @arminb, it would be a miracle if it could reduce 255 characters down to an 8.3 short name with a reversible algorithm. Instead `GetLongPathName`  has to read the long filenames as stored in the filesystem for an existing file.  It loops over the path elements, calling [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and joining the `cFileName` elements from the resulting [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures.

Comment: @falsetru, from the [`GetLongPathName` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): [D]o not assume that you can skip calling `GetLongPathName` if the path does not contain a tilde (~) character.